# Implementing Simpson's Rule math.net numerics

Tags: c#, numerical-integration, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to implement Simpson's Rule using the math.net numerics library.  The method that I would like to use takes four arguments, a Func (function pointer), intervalBegin, intervalEnd and partitionNumbers.  Currently I am testing the method using Math.Sin, but can someone help me to understand how this Func should be implemented?

```
var test = MathNet.Numerics.Integration.SimpsonRule.IntegrateComposite(Math.Sin, 1, 4, 20);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Additional material**:
Pic taken directly from [math is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-introduction.html).
You can have absolutely any mathematical function like the one char below represents.

[image]

Integration calculates area between the line that function draws and X axis.

The reason I say function you pass into Simpsons integration doesn't matter is because ANY function can be used as long as it fits "1 number in, 1 number out" format.

**End of additional materia**l.

Simpson's formula is an integration which means it needs a mathematical function to calculate with. Below is the rough formula of simpson's integration (using numbers you passed as arguments and a random function) if you are interested, if not skip this part .

```
intervalBegin = 1; 
intervalEnd = 4;
partitionNumbers = 20;
f(x) = 3x^2;

deltaX = (intervalEnd - intervalBegin) / partitionNumbers;
SimpsonsIntegration = deltaX/3 * (f(intervalBegin) + 4*f(intervalBegin + deltaX*1)+ 2*f(intervalBegin + deltaX*2)+ 4*f(intervalBegin + deltaX*3)+ 2*f(intervalBegin + deltaX*4).....+4*f(intervalBegin + deltaX*19) +f(intervalEnd);
```

The function in Simpsons integration is ANY function that takes 1 numeric argument and returns one. (it might be type specific like float or double)

```
public double anyFunction(double number){ 
   double result = [calculations];
   return calculations;

}
```

Your call could look like this:

```
MathNet.Numerics.Integration.SimpsonRule.IntegrateComposite(anyFunction, 1, 4, 20);
```

Comment: I did not understand yet what the Func should do.  Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Func is supposed to be any mathematical function. It can be function can be "x^2" it can be "Math.Pi*r^2". I'll edit my post in a sec, it might give you some context.

Comment: That's means I can use Math.Sin as well as Math.Pi?

Comment: Math.Pi will not work, because I believe it's a simple variable or a property, not a method. You can use your own function:
MathNet.Numerics.Integration.SimpsonRule.IntegrateComposite(anyFunction, 1, 4, 20);

check out some edits

Comment: Any hint how to create anyFunction?

Comment: second block of code in my answer. The [calculations] part is completely up to you. It can be calculation of area it can be something much more complex.

Comment: Right now I just need something simple, later when I know more I could think on something more complex.  Can I ask a silly question? how to calculate each block under the line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63205/discussion-between-zero-and-doro).

Comment: I am sorry, I am at work and some security policy do not allow me to access the chat.  What abut by email?

Comment: I see, I was saying if you want a simple function just replace [calculations] with square area: "number*number" (without quotation marks). Everything should work.

Comment: I did and it seems to work.  I just got an update on the requirements; the intervals are not equals.  So I guess that Simpson’s Rule would not fit.  Do you some other approach except of Riemann Sum?